# How to create an index in ElasticSearch and push data from streaming query?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-structured-streaming

Not able to create an index and push the data to elasticsearch using elastic sink

```
df.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("es.nodes","localhost:9200")
  .option("checkpointLocation","/tmp/")
  .option("es.resource","index/type")
  .start
```

There are no errors, unfortunately it is not working.

at times(1 out of 10) above snippet creates new index but it doesn't push data of the dataframe/dataset to index created. Remaining times it doesn't even create a index. It seems something with properties of elastic search configurations.

Comment: @sandeepreddy Start with `format("console")` first to understand how `outputMode("append")` works. How do you create the streaming query (`df`)? What does it do?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, format("console") works perfectly. Dataframe/Dataset is being created after reading the data from kafka sink using readstream and format as "kafka".  Trying to write the output of Kafka read stream to Elastic Search.

Comment: Re _"works perfectly."_ does the query give you results regularly as expected? Just checking...

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, yes results are as expected. Apart from that I can successfully write dataframe/dataset  back to Kafka as a part of WriteStream

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I'm facing a slightly similar issue that I have posted here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64729505/pysparks-df-writestream-generates-no-output . I'm stuck and can't seem to get it to work . Could you please take a look and help me if you can ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @sandeepreddy I too have the same scenario but i am facing the issue
'''Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[tvk]]: {"tvk":{"2":6,"1":13,"0":4}}}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE'''

Comment: @Beluga, I believe your topic has three partitions, you might need to update kafka consumer to read from those specific offsets i.e 2nd partition 6th offset or reset offsets to latest.. Even if this do not work, we might need to work with spark checkpoint folder, deleting the checkpoint folder might help

Comment: @sandeepreddy Yeah it was an issue with checkpoints. Its working now. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

From one of the OP's comments:

Solved. The time column being used with WithWaterMark option should be a real time streaming value. My testing data is a dump taken from production which is old dated time value , post the correction of time column to current time stamp,it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
df.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("es")
  .option("es.nodes","localhost")
  .option("es.port","9200")
  .option("checkpointLocation","/tmp/")
  .start("index/type")
```

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master);
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true");
```

Refer the official document for more help
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html

Comment: It works for a normal dataframe/dataset which does not have WithWaterMark conditions. If the dataframe/dataset is created by the means of water mark and windowing time this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give elastic-hadoop library from maven repository in order to do that.[Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop)

After that use this:

```
df.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("checkpointLocation","GiveCheckPointingName").option("es.port","9200").option("es.nodes","LocalHost").start("indexname/indextype").awaitTermination()
```